# Finance historical options data (with strikes etc) on google finance API

Tags: yahoo-finance, google-finance, google-finance-api

Can anyone provide how to get historical options data with strikes by Google Finance API? Mbe Yahoo API can do it?
Thx.

Comment: alternatively, you can obtain option data manually via [CBOE](http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx)

Comment: on google/finance its are more easly than via CBOE. At google I can use json-data via http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?cid=358464&expd=21&expm=4&expy=2012&output=json

Comment: I grabbed some data (15 min tick, for 1 months, for MSFT, Exxon) so if someone in future needed this data for education purposes, pls contact me - I will send you mysql database dump.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no free API that lets you query for historical option prices easily.

Your best shot may be to collect it daily for the stocks you're interested in:
http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&output=json

Comment: do you know of any way to specify the options expiration in the URL? Currently it only seems to download the most recent expiration.

Comment: The format seems to be
http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&expd=31&expm=12&expy=2015&output=json

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen free historical option data prices. Neither Yahoo or Google provide them. I downloaded 2012 end of day data from optiondata.net. It includes daily prices, greeks and IV. As far as I can tell it seems accurate. There are several other paid sources out there but I have not tested their data.

Comment: optiondata.net is now gone, don't click the link