# Guide to using google URL to get options chain data?

Tags: google-finance

I'd like to enter a URL into google and get all options chain data for a particular stock.  Is there a guide that shows you how to use it, like if I wanted to grab all options that expire in the next year without knowing the individual expiration dates, or if I just wanted a particular strike price?  I found another question that gives me the basic outline, but doesn't specify the details:

[Finance historical options data (with strikes etc) on google finance API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649052/finance-historical-options-data-with-strikes-etc-on-google-finance-api)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to do this using the ImportHTML function, although there is a delay in the data of course.

```
=importhtml("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=QQQ&m=2013-12","table",0)
```